Ubuntu Boot Repair - Verification failed 0x1A
I previously asked about repairing the boot on my Ubuntu dual boot with Win11, which had stopped booting to Ubuntu after a Win update.
I've got a USB with Boot Repair on it, Universal USB Installer plus an .iso of Ubuntu 24.04.1 from the ubuntu/download page.
I put the USB in the computer, restart but it does not see the drive. I press [Esc] to bring up the boot menu, choose the USB but I get a blue screen saying
Verifiction failed: (0x1A) Security Violation
I have to [OK] this, then it brings up a blue screen saying
Shim UEFI key management / Press any key to perform MOK management
I [OK] this and it brings up a further blue screen saying
Perform MOK management
with a menu
Continue Boot
Enroll key from disk
Enroll hash from disk
I do not know what to do next, advice would be useful. Please bear in mind I am an absolute novice with Ubuntu, and know nothing about coding or commands.

In the end it seems Ubuntu is not for me and it appears I can just delete it then reassign the disc space, so... I won't need an answer any longer. However, if someone reads and can answer, maybe others can benefit from that.
